# CentOS 6.5 Server Lockup

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, server-crashes, hosting

Today one of our CentOS 6.5 KVM nodes from OVH crashed after 46 days of uptime and we were unable to find the reason why, we had this issue before with the OVH kernel on another server but this one is running a normal kernel:

`Linux 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 25 19:59:55 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Our monitoring tools showed the following:

[image]

Looks like a very high load even though no VM's were doing anything strange.

I took a look at the `/var/log/messages/` file at first it showed nothing during the downtime:

```
    Jun 16 11:15:11 server dhcpd: DHCPINFORM from 5.XXX.XX.104 via viifbr0
    Jun 16 11:15:11 server dhcpd: DHCPACK to 5.XXX.XX.104 (02:XX:00:XX:XX:d3) via viifbr0
                         -----Downtime no logs-----
    Jun 16 12:24:01 server kernel: imklog 5.8.10, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
    Jun 16 12:24:01 server rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.10" x-pid="1493" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
    Jun 16 12:24:01 server kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
    Jun 16 12:24:01 server kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
```

I checked `dmesg` as well, although I'm not sure what the output means since most of it looks normal:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=YyRCYZdn

I'm unsure what this could be, are there any other logs I could check?

Answer (score 0):

When you debug VM crashes you need to have the collaboration of the hosting provider. The high load seems to be after the crash. This makes me think that the Linux running on the physical server has crashed or had problems (e.g. running very slow, storage problems...).

Comment: I'm talking about our KVM node (which is indeed our own dedicated server) that crashed. We ourselfs are running KVM VM's on them.